# ActiveX and .NET

Tags: .net, com, activex, dcom

I used to work with DCOM (out process exe) and COM (inprocess dll) in delphi language.
Is there any substitute for them in .NET language?
Does Microsoft still uses the concept of ActiveX?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a COM interface for your .NET class by decorating your .NET class with various attributes. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx) for a tutorial.

ActiveX is basically just "COM in a web-page" so it continues to be supported by virtue of .NET's support for COM. However, distributing ActiveX objects is a lot more difficult - see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484326/deploy-c-activex-in-a-cab-for-internet-explorer-use).

Generally speaking, VB.NET has better support for COM than C#. However, for other .NET development, C# is the more popular language.