# To Deploy .net com dll as a cab which registers in server

Tags: .net

how To Deploy .net com dll  (activex) as a cab which register in server

I tried with this inf file.

[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
so.DLL=so.DLL

[so.DLL]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={CLSID:EB27D320-F48E-45c1-BCA8-4DEEEFD54E0D}
FileVersion=1,0,0,0
RegisterServer=yes
hook=DOTNET_INSTALLER

[DOTNET_INSTALLER]
run=%EXTRACT_DIR%\regasm.exe %EXTRACT_DIR%\so.dll

Comment: why wouldn't you use a msi installer?

Comment: how to install with msi installer?

Comment: After thinking more, i realized you wouldn't want an msi for a ActiveX object. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484326/deploy-c-activex-in-a-cab-for-internet-explorer-use appears to be a duplicate though

Comment: they created SampInst.msi for cab installation

Comment: I am getting this error.

Comment: error : The Inf file you selected does not support this method of installtion.