# Writing an ActiveX Control in .NET

Tags: asp.net, activex

plz check this tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx

how i use usercontrol in my asp.net website.

I am add reference in my asp.net website and use the  tag but i can not able to see that control

Comment: Could you supply a bit more detail please?  How are you using the tag, and what exactly happens?

Comment: i download that code from url u can see in link and that user control i want to use in my asp.net website i use <object> tag and also give the reference of dll file but control is not able to load

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484326/deploy-c-activex-in-a-cab-for-internet-explorer-use/5484527#5484527

Comment: But please give more details - what browser, what are you hoping to achieve, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly.... a UserControl is a base class i.e. you must inherit from that to create your own implementations (or concrete types).

Once you've done that you're off and away!

EDIT: maybe another issue you're having is that you don't have a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll in your project and you *can't* create your own UserControl implementation... not sure as the question is a little vague  :(

EDIT 2: Ok, thinking about this further (and given your confusion still :) I think you might be needing something else... not ActiveX controls as the article you link to relates. I think you actually are interested in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx) and possibly [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/myusercontrol.aspx)
User controls in ASP.NET and ActiveX controls are very very different (nothing alike in fact!)
I hope this helps shed some more light!

Comment: cheesus plz can u explain me... i can't understand

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you link to is from 2003, and a lot has changed in the meantime in terms of embedding controls and security issues.

As far as I know (related to IE8), an ActiveX has to implement IObjectSafety, and needs to be signed or the website needs to be trusted to execute it.

Comment: so plz suggest me other example it's urgent